# In Wpf GridView how can i bind a control to another inside one Item

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, binding

I want to hide/show the TextBox in the item according to the checkbox. But just in that Item where both controls are.

I have the BoolToVis converter.

```
 <ListView Name="lst1" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox  IsChecked="False" Name="chbVis"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="Visibility"></TextBlock>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="Field" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=chbVis, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"></TextBlock>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                </GridViewColumn>
             </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, by creating a property in the Field class for binding the checkbox.

```
public bool fieldVis;
    public bool FieldVis
    {
        get { return fieldVis; }
        set
        {
            fieldVis= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

And then the xaml looks like:

```
 <ListView Name="lst1" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding FieldVis}" Name="chbVis"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="Visibility"></TextBlock>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="Field" Visibility="{Binding fieldVis, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"></TextBlock>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                </GridViewColumn>
             </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

It works like charm.